# # of DISTINCT sequences of numbers $a_1, ..., a_n$ (sometimes $a_i=a_{i+1}$)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

As from the title, given a sequence of number $a_1, ...,  a_n$ I would like to know how many  number of different sequences exist taking into account that same numbers might exist.

Examples:

f(0003) = 4 since we can have (0003, 0030, 0300, 3000),

f(0012) = 12 since we can have (0012,0021,0102,0120,0201,0210,1002,1020,1200,2001,2010,2100)

Comment: Hint: There are $n!$ ways of arranging $n$ objects in a row. If $k$ of these $n$ objects are the same, then there will be $k!$ counts of the same combination for each distinct combination out of the $n!$. What do you have to do to get rid of this $k!$ over counting?

Comment: I KNOW :-) !! $n!/k!$

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: GRANDE!!  Put it as a solution, so I can mark your answer as correct if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: There are $n!$ ways of arranging $n$ objects in a row. If $k$ of these $n$ objects are the same, then there will be $k!$ counts of the same combination for each distinct combination out of the $n!$. What do you have to do to get rid of this $k!$ over counting?

The correct answer is $\frac{n!}{k!}$.